# Install eclipse plugin BPMN2-Modeler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, bpmn

I'm trying to install the **BPMN2-Modeler plugin** on **Eclipse Neon**.

I followed the [installation instructions of the BPMN2-Modeler wiki page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/BPMN2-Modeler).

I tried using `http://download.eclipse.org/bpmn2-modeler/updates/neon/` as the update site URL (in "Help -> Install New Software").

But it only returns `"could not find http://download.eclipse.org/bpmn2-modeler/updates/neon/"`.

[image: error message: "could not find http://download.eclipse.org/bpmn2-modeler/updates/neon/"]

[JBOSS points to same installation instructions](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMEclipse.html#d0e12825), so I might be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the version at the end of the URL (`1.3.2` in that case).

The final update site URL (in "Help -> Install New Software") was: `http://download.eclipse.org/bpmn2-modeler/updates/neon/1.3.2/`

[image: Correct update site URL for Eclipse Neon's BPMN2-Modeler plugin]

---

Note that [Graphiti](https://eclipse.org/graphiti/download.php) also provides BPMN2-Modeler plugin in his Graphiti update site for Neon: `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon`.

[image: Eclipse Graphiti download instructions]

[image: Eclipse Graphiti - BPMN2-Modeler plugin available]